# CSS - problem with show a sub item under a <li>

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I try to make a list menu with a submenu using JSX(React) and css Pure (Not jquery!). My intention is show  "box-blue" under the `<li>` "Technologies" but I don't know how to make the div "box-blue" stay visible when I move out from the `<li>` "Techonologies" element. (obviously always inside the `<div>` "box-blue")

```
           <ul className="display-menu">
                <li className="display-menu-item"><NavLink className="link-categories" exact to="/">Technologies</NavLink>
                    <div className="box-blue"></div>
                </li>
                <li className="display-menu-item"><NavLink className="link-categories" exact to="/">Furniture</NavLink></li>
                <li className="display-menu-item"><NavLink className="link-categories" to="/">Entertainment</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
```

CSS code

```
.display-menu-item{
    margin-left: 1rem;
    position:relative;
  }

.link-categories{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 0.85rem; 
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:10rem;
  }

.box-blue{
    height:25rem;
    width: 80rem;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25.5rem;  /* the box appears under the ul  */
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    right: -45.5rem; /* the box appears at center  */
  }

.link-categories:hover ~ .box-blue{
    display:block;
  }
```

Comment: when do you want to "display: none;" again?

Comment: again? , display is "none" just once